# Get Transaction Details from PayPal SDK Android

Tags: android, sdk, paypal

I integrated PayPal Mobile Payments into my Application. That was no big deal. I have it set up that when a customer makes a purchase from my app the details are are posted to my server. No big deal either. But, for the life of me, I cannot get the PayPal transaction details. I see the details in the LogCat but No matter what I try I cannot grab anything. I know it has to be simple but I have been sitting here and every attempt is fruitless. I can get some of the details but not all. Any help would be appreciated. I didn't do anything Dramatic to the Code Posted on the PayPal developer site yet until I fully get the grasp of their SDK but here it is.

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                    // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                    // for more details.








//String PAYMENT_CONFIRMATION = confirm.toJSONObject().getJSONObject("pay_key").toString();
                    //  Log.d("PAYMENT CONFIRMATION KEY::", PAYMENT_CONFIRMATION)   ;




               new Update_CloseLines().execute();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        }
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
```

Here is the logcat.

```
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830): {
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     "payment": {
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "short_description": "Nite Rider Hollow",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "amount": "1.01",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "currency_code": "USD"
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     },
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     "client": {
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "platform": "Android",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.3",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "product_name": "PayPal Android SDK; ",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "environment": "live"
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     },
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     "proof_of_payment": {
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         "adaptive_payment": {
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):             "timestamp": "2013-08-26T18:03:55+0000",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):             "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):             "app_id": "APP-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):             "pay_key": "AP-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):         }
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830):     }
08-26 13:04:01.780: I/paymentExample(830): }
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830): an extremely unlikely failure occurred: 
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830): org.json.JSONException: No value for pay_key
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:569)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at com.example.shopper.ConfirmCheckOut.onActivityResult(ConfirmCheckOut.java:480)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-26 13:04:01.780: E/paymentExample(830):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 13:04:01.850: E/SpannableStringBuilder(830): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-26 13:04:01.850: E/SpannableStringBuilder(830): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

If I could, I would like to grab the pay_key.

Unlikely ERROR:

```
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971): an extremely unlikely failure occurred: 
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971): org.json.JSONException: Value AP-6S9448074V032801M at pay_key of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at com.example.shopper.ConfirmCheckOut.onActivityResult(ConfirmCheckOut.java:480)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-26 14:13:27.115: E/paymentExample(13971):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where's the code that's actually supposed to get the pay_key?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have tried quite a few different things. I added the code that gave the Logcat error.

Comment: You still need to navigate the DOM inside the JSON. I would expect your code to fail. Try this instead: `confirm.toJSONObject().getJSONObject("proof_of_payment").getJSONObject("adaptive_payment").getJSONObject("pay_key")`

Comment: It threw an "Unlikely" Error.

Comment: Should be: `confirm.toJSONObject().getJSONObject("proof_of_payment").getJSONObject("adaptiv‌​e_payment").getString("pay_key")`

Comment: Don't forgot loads of error checking around this ;)

Comment: Hi,I am also trying to integrate the paypal android SDK with my application. I integrated everything as per the documentation. but when i press the buy button paypal screen is getting displayed. but call back to Activity Results is coming immediately with resultCode as RESULT_CANCELED. can you please suggest me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: public void initPaymentService() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
startService(intent);
}

Comment: public void onBuyPressed(String amount){
PayPalPayment toBuy=new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans");
Intent i=new Intent(this,PaymentActivity.class);
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT,ENVIRONMENT);
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_ID);
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL,RECEIVER_EMAIL);
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID,"someuser@somedomain.com");
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID,"credential-from-developer.paypal.com");  
i.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,toBuy);
startActivityForResult(i,0);
}

Answer (score 2):

For production applications, you'll really want send the whole confirmation JSON to your server. There it can be parsed and the `pay_key` or `payment_id` can be used to get transaction details by querying the proper API. (See https://developer.paypal.com)

The security context given to a mobile device is more restrictive since the app will get installed on devices outside your control.

See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/ for a more detailed explanation.